# angularjs extjs combination

Tags: angularjs, extjs4.2

I'm using combination of angularjs and extjs 
using this seed https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed/

everything works fine until I got problem when I need to POST the grid store sync value..
it send OPTIONS value, not POST as usual

I've tried override ext ajax request but failed
    Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.override({
        actionMethods : {
        create : 'POST',
        read   : 'GET',
        update : 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
       }
    });

this is the sync button
        var saveButton = Ext.create('Ext.Action', {
            text: 'Save',
            disabled: false,
            handler: function(){
                grid.getStore().sync();
            }
        });

this is the requested page
[image: extjs4 request with angular]

this is non-angular version
[image: extsj4 request without angular]

the extjs code wrap inside angular controller, how could I solve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: I don't think so, it's not about send cross domain..